# Bridging Ports help

Tags: networking

I have a bridge in place right now for my virtual machines using br0 with a virtual interface and eth0 but I now want to be able to monitor my network via adding a second Ethernet card and bridging the two physical Ethernet cards together.

What would be the best thing to in terms of keeping my existing bridge running and adding this new one. Can I create multiple bridges? Will this new bridge affect my existing one?

Thanks,

Jerden

Comment: That would be interesting... However, I do not see a need for a bridge on eth1 if you don't need to access your virtual OS. That being said `bridge_ports eth0 eth1` should do what you would expect...

Comment: I have them bridged as they are Windows servers acting as storage servers for people. So they need to be fully accessible 24/7 from the local network. We also have other devices attached to the network, non virtualised and I want to be able to monitor the traffic they produced through the Ubuntu server that's running.